# Is it possible to nest git repos, but only have one Github repo

Tags: git, github

I know there are a lot of questions for "how to nest git repos", and most of them recommend submodules. However, all the code snippets I've seen have the submodule connected to a separate git url. In my case, my only git remotes are on GitHub, but I would like the submodules to not be visible in the index. Admittedly my reasoning for this is somewhat shallow; I have over 150 repos and I want to combine a bunch of them to make the list more navigatable. However I don't want to lose the revision histories.

Right now I see only two options, neither of which seems suitable:

1. Merge all the commit histories into a single tree
2. Keep the status quo, where every repo is viewable through Github.

Answer (score 1):

No.

A “GitHub repo” is exactly one Git repo. While there *are* ways to sort of achieve this using Git (via submodules or merging the repos into one), but you’ve already eliminated them as non-viable.

Answer (score 1):

> Merge all the commit histories into a single tree

That is the monorepo approach, and you see that used more and more by big organization (Facebook, Google, Microsoft)

Microsoft has [one giant Git repo for Windows](https://techcrunch.com/2017/05/24/microsoft-now-uses-git-and-gvfs-to-develop-windows/), but that is because it uses [GVFS (Git Virtual FileSystem)](https://github.com/Microsoft/GVFS)

In your case, you can try and [merge your repo (with git subtree for instance)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14992078/6309) (or, [as another option, some `merge --squash`](https://leewc.com/articles/how-to-merge-multiple-git-repositories-into-one-repo/))

Answer (score 1):

You can treat the whole repositories like just one using subtrees.

I think solution could be [subtrees](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree). With subtree you can develop in your central repository also elements stored in others repository.

This means that you can have

- main project
- component A
- component B

You can put components A and B in separates repository. With their own readme file and so on. Those are not independent libraries: are just a part (a sub tree) of your project.

### update the component X

To update the component X you can just clone the component and update it. But wait, ... this is a bit confusing so, ... you can just pull subtree inside main git repository and push the subtree in its remote.